# What next when the user is logged?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-apps-script, web-applications, firebase-authentication

I am trying to integrate google auth from Firebase into my web app (on GAS), and i am having a hard time. I am new to it and have few experience in developing so excuse my lack of precision.

I managed to implement several steps but fail to come back to navigate the app normally once the user has logged.

First, here are the steps that are working fine (at least they seem to):

1. doGet() returns `HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('auth')` which contains all the necessary code for the authentication.
2. 'auth.html' calls necessary stuff from firebase via CDN and the behaviour is correct: if i am not logged: UI shows and if i am logged: user details show on screen.
3. Since i need the userID to go on with the server-side scripts, i pass the userID which for now is just used to check i have the value on server side (is that correct to use userID this way?);

**EDITED QUESTION:**

Now what i would like to understand is the best practice for the steps

1. User opens app
2. doGet() is run and loads 'auth.html'
3. client-side authentication runs and collects user data
4. userID is set as a variable to be passed to server
5. then in order to run the rest of the scripts (the real app content user needs to see) what is the way to go? Should some function be run through `google.script.run.someFunction(userID)` when user is logged that would run the 'normal' app content (as it was before i integrated any authentication to be clear)?

last question: Does the authentication needs to be run on every page before loading content?

Here is my code:

.gs

```
    function doGet(e) {
    return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('auth2')
    .setXFrameOptionsMode(HtmlService.XFrameOptionsMode.ALLOWALL)
    .setTitle('FirebaseUI | Firebase Authentication');
    }
```

auth.html

```
    <base target="_top">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.14.2/firebase-app.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.14.2/firebase-auth.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/libs/firebaseui/3.5.2/firebaseui.js"></script>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.firebase.com/libs/firebaseui/3.5.2/firebaseui.css" />
    <script>
        var firebaseConfig = {
          apiKey: "stackoverflow",
          authDomain: "stackoverflow.firebaseapp.com",
          databaseURL: "https://stackoverflow-default-rtdb.europe-west1.firebasedatabase.app",
          projectId: "stackoverflow",
          storageBucket: "stackoverflow.appspot.com",
          messagingSenderId: "267227785525",
          appId: "1:stackoverflow:web:stackoverflow",
          measurementId: "G-stackoverflow"
        };
        firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
    </script>
    <script>

        google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(url) {
            var uiConfig = {
                signInFlow: 'redirect',
                signInSuccessUrl: url,
                signInOptions: [
                    firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID
                ],
            };
            var ui = new firebaseui.auth.AuthUI(firebase.auth());
            var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
            console.log(user);
            if (user) {
                document.getElementById("signOut").style.display = "inline-block";
            } else {
                ui.start('#firebaseui-auth-container', uiConfig);
            }
        })
        .webAppUrl();

    </script>
    <script>
        initApp = function() {
            firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
                if (user) {
                    user.getIdToken().then(function(accessToken) {
                        document.getElementById('account-details').textContent = JSON.stringify({
                            displayName: user.displayName,
                            email: user.email,
                            custom: user.email,
                            emailVerified: user.emailVerified,
                            phoneNumber: user.phoneNumber,
                            photoURL: user.photoURL, // remove quotes to get the photoURL
                            uid: user.uid,
                            accessToken: "hidden", // replace "hidden" with accessToken
                            providerData: user.providerData // remove quotes to get the photoURL
                        }, null, '  ');
                    });
                  const userID = user.email;
                  google.script.run.someFunction(userID);
                } else {
                    document.getElementById('account-details').textContent = '';
                }
            });
        };
        window.addEventListener('load', function() {
            initApp();
        });
    </script>
</head>
```

Here the documentation i read:
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication
https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/google-signin

Comment: It doesn't make sense to call doGet from the client-side `google.script.run.doGet(userId)`... It looks that this question needs more focus. P.S. the question doesn't include the web app deployment settings, once you decided on what you will focus the question, add a [mcve].

Comment: Please read https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication

Comment: The question still needs more focus.

Comment: what do you mean by "more focus" ? That the question isn't accurate enough? I wouldn't know how to be more precise.
I just don't get what should be the pattern of loading of an app with authentication, i have all the pieces but can't get the order they are supposed to follow. Do i need to put the authentication code above the home html, hiding the content by default and then displaying it if the authentication succeeds? Do i need to redirect to another html file containing the content i want to show? I have the feeling authentication stuff requires too much knowledge.

Comment: The question is embracing several concepts that looks that aren't understood / applied correctly. I suggest you to create a [mcve] (mcve) focused on client-server communication without the Firebase Authentication part. This "mcve" should include the web app manifest, the server side code for the doGet function, the client-side code to communicate with the server-side. Once you have this working, extend the previous "mcve" to include the Firebase Authentication but only if you really needed. If you need help to make the first "mcve" work, post a new question.

Comment: ok thanks i'll try to do it. Trying to add the authentication to my web app without understanding it just makes it more complicated as i have to much code/files there indeed. Creating the mcve will require time though so I'll post it when i manage to do it. Thanks again for the patience